# How can I force MIDL to output a CLSID for an empty coclass?

Tags: com, idl, midl

I have a declaration in the library block of my project's IDL file like so:

```
[uuid(...), helpstring(...)]
coclass MyClass;
```

The only interfaces this class implements are standard Microsoft-defined interfaces (such as IPersistPropertyBag2).  If I include them in the definition of "MyClass", then they get sucked into the type library, which I do not want.  The problem is that, if I leave the interface list empty as above, then MIDL won't include the class in the generated header files or type library.

So the question is: how do I force MIDL to include "MyClass" in the type library?

Or, even better: how can I force MIDL to *exclude* certain interfaces in a coclass from the type library?

Comment: You can't.  Just create a dummy interface with no methods.

Comment: Not the response I was hoping for, but thanks for your reply.